# Error 2 error C2679: binary '/' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have some problem about operator overloading. I looked everywhere but couldn't find a proper solution for this error. Here is some parts of my code :

```
Matrix<type> Matrix<type>::operator/(const Matrix& denom){

if(num_of_rows != denom.num_of_rows || num_of_cols != denom.num_of_cols)
    throw string("Unable to divide (Different size).");
if(denom.contains(0))
    throw string("Unable to divide (Divide by zero).");

for(int i = 0; i < num_of_rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < num_of_cols; j++)
        values[i][j] /= denom.values[i][j]; 
                    // I KNOW THIS IS NOT HOW TO DIVIDE TWO MATRICES

return *this;
 }

 void Matrix<type>::operator=(const Matrix& m) const {

delete [][] values;
num_of_rows = m.num_of_rows;
num_of_cols = m.num_of_cols;
values = new type*[num_of_rows];

for(int i = 0; i < num_of_rows; i++){
    *(values + i) = new type[num_of_cols];
    for(int j = 0; j < num_of_cols; j++)
        values[i][j] = m.values[i][j];
}
 }
```

And this is the Matrix class and the constructor takes 2 arguments :

```
class Matrix{

private:
    type** values;
    int num_of_rows, num_of_cols;

public:
    Matrix(){}
    Matrix(int, int);
    type getElement(int, int);
    void print();
    bool contains(type);
    Matrix<type> operator/(const Matrix&);
    void operator=(const Matrix&) const;
};

template <class type>

Matrix<type>::Matrix(int rows, int cols){

values = new type*[rows];
num_of_rows = rows;
num_of_cols = cols;

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    *(values + i) = new type[cols];
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            type random = (type)rand() / 3276.71;
        values[i][j] = random;
    }
}
}
```

And this piece of code in main gives this error :

```
srand(time(NULL));
Matrix<int> m1(3,5);  // creating some objects 
Matrix<double> m2(3,5);  // matrices’ elements are assigned randomly from 0 to 10
Matrix<double> m3(5,5);
Matrix<double> m4(5,6);
if(!(m2.contains(0))){
    Matrix<double> m8(3,5);
    m8=m1/m2; // THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
    m8.print();
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to what's at hand, but your `operator=` is not safe for self-assignment. It would be customary to copy the values into a temporary array, then swap a pointer to that array with `values` before finally deleting the old buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m1` has type `Matrix<int>`, so when looking up for a suitable overload of `operator/` we find:

```
Matrix<int> Matrix<int>::operator/(const Matrix& denom);
```

Note that the parameter type `Matrix` here makes use of the so-called injected class name. That means `Matrix` stands in this case for `Matrix<int>`, since that's the (template) class in question. However `m2`, the argument to the call to `operator/`, has type `Matrix<double>`. There is no suitable conversion from `Matrix<double>` to `Matrix<int>` so the call is invalid.

A possible fix is to change `operator/` to also be a template:

```
// Declared inside Matrix<type>:
template<typename Other>
Matrix& operator/=(Matrix<Other> const& other);
```

(I also took the liberty of fixing the operator to better reflect what it's actually doing.)

However you'll then run into the problem that you're using a `Matrix<int>` (the result of the call to `operator/`) to assign to `m8` which has type `Matrix<double>`. So perhaps you need an `operator=` to do a conversion (in which case I'd recommend a converting constructor as well, or perhaps even just a converting constructor without a converting `operator=`).

Answer (score 0):

The error message quite clearly states that you haven't defined a division operator taking the two types as arguments you are passing. Looking at the code excerpt this is the case: There is an operator taking two `Matrix<T>` but none taking a`Matrix<T1>` and a `Matrix<T2>` (for different type `T1` and `T2`).

BTW, what is your question?